# Intersections of sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose that we have U an open set and A a subset of a metric space X.We can assume that the $U \cap A$ is also open ??

Because in a proof that I'm studing it says:

$(X,p)$ is a separable metric space and A is a subset of X, we want to show that A is also separable.

We have that because X is separable , there exist a countable family of open sets $\mathcal{O}$ of subsets of X with the property: that for every open $G\subseteq X$ and $x\in G$ there exist $U\in \mathcal{O}$ s.t $x\in U \subseteq G$

Then the countable family of sets $\mathcal{O}=\left \{ U\cap A :U\in \mathcal{O} \right \}$ has open subsets of A.

My question is why $U \cap A$ is open ??

Comment: It is open *in the subspace* $A$, but it needn't be open in $X$. In metric spaces, the subspace topology coincides with the metric topology for the subspace.

Answer (score 0):

No. Suppose that your space is $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, that $X=\mathbb R$ and that $A=\{0\}$. Then $X$ is open, but $X\cap A$ is not.

Concerning your other question, what is said is that $U\cap A$ is an open subset of $A$ (and it is), not of the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

$U\cap A$ is an open subspace of $A$ by definition of the subspace topology. Note that $U\cap A$ is not necessarily open as a subset of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

$U\cap A$ is open in the subspace topology on $A$. That's just the definition of the subspace topology. And it's the relevant meaning of "open" when you want to decide whether $A$ is separable as a topological space in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

"We can assume that the U∩A is also open?"

If $A \subset X$, and $U\subset X$ and $U$ is open *in the space $X$*.

We can not assume $A \cap U$ is open *in the space $X$* for obvious reasons. (It just ain't.)

By definition $A \cap U$ is open *in the subspace $A \subset X$*.  That is the definition of "subspace".

This question is about separability of $A$ as a topological subspace of $X$.  In context, the author thought it was clear than talking of open sets he was talking of sets that are open in $A$, not sets that are open in $X$.

Simple example:  $X = \mathbb R; A = [0, \infty); U = (-1,1); U \cap A = [0, 1)$.

$[0,1)$ is not open in $\mathbb R$.  $[0,1)$ *is* open in $[0, \infty)$.